# SDRAM Voltage and pin planner consequences

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus, sdram

I have this SDRAM module:
[image]

According to the [docs](https://www.issi.com/WW/pdf/42-45R-S_86400D-16320D-32160D.pdf): am I right that it's the 3,3V version?

If yes: what are the consequences of that fact using the Pin Planner?
Is it correct that I have to set the I/O standard setting of all pins that go into the RAM to 3.3LVTTL? The default current strength is 12mA, I couldn't find any information about that topic in the datasheet. Is that value correct?
[image]

**Correction**
After choosing 3.3V LVTTL in the pin planner the default current strength went down to 8mA (default)

Comment: What is "the Pin Planner"?

Comment: I would’ve chosen 3.3V lvcmos at a guess. I’d confirm by referring to the de10 board documentation and there should be plenty of examples of sdram usage on that board. Note that you show a sdram chip, not a sdram module.

Comment: 12 mA sounds like a lot. Typically, TTL drivers go within 0.7-0.3V of the rail and can deliver 4mA, and CMOS drivers do not want to but can deliver 2mA all the way to the rail.

Comment: What version of Quartus are u using? Does the IP core for the SDRAM show the pin settings?

Comment: @brhans: The pin planner is part of Quartus (software). An Intel IDE (Integrated Development Environment) for developing projects based on Intel FPGAs.